# How do I check that Kotlin Math class operating normally at Huawei device?

Tags: android, mobile, huawei-developers

I've made an app at Kotlin for target 30 SDK. It works fine at Android Studio Emulators and Google based phones (Xiaomi as example). The app is started fine on Huawei devices, but crashes in the middle of working.

The app is used next techniques: Mutable Live Data, Shared View Model. In view, that app starts OK, Mutable Live Data and Shared View Models works fine for some time. In the middle of app running some math calculations start.
I have several guessing about an issue:
First, the problem, that Huawei device is not familiar with a class Math at Kotlin language.
Second, the problem, that Maven Central is not supported at Huawei devices.
Third, I have no idea what can run wrong.
I appreciate the answers with next ideas:
First, the IDE to test on Huawei devices.
Second, own experience with difficult of adaptation of app for Google for app for Huawei.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the error message and stacktrace you get when it crashes on Huawei device.

Comment: The problem is - I don't have the error message. The problem is not occured during run at Android Studio. Can I emulate Huawei device under Android Studio?

Comment: Probably not. How do you know it crashes on Hueawei devices?

Comment: The app crashes at Huawei devices. I made a release apk. The size of apk file is about 5 Mb, so it can be easily sent by e-mail. I installed the apk on two physical devices: Huawei and Xiaomi (common Google). It works at Xiaomi and crashes on Huawei. Also, I tried to release the apk through Huawei Store and Ru Store. The both stores test the apk on Huawei. The apk is also crashes on Huawei there.

Comment: but if it crashed on the device, you can get the logcat off that device. Also, if the stores test and the app crashes, they should make the crash report available to you.

Comment: In Huawei developer console should be feature to run you APK on real Huawei device and watch logs.